# Finding the position of a list in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list

```
{Break, Break, Break, Break, Break, Break, Break, Break, Break, \
Break, Break, Break, Break, Break, Break, Break, Break, Break, Break, \
Break, Break, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 
  0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
   0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, Break, Break, Break, Break, Break, Break}
```

and I want to find the positions of the elements of the form {0,...,-1,...,0}. I tried using the function `Position[specialColumns[[I]], _?(# =!= Break &)]`, but it is not working. I also tried the command

```
Table[If[specialColumns[[I]] != Break, I, Break], {I, 
  Length[specialColumns]}]
```

But is also not giving me any result. Any suggestions?

Comment: try `Position[specialColumns, Except[Break], 1]`? Btw, [I ($\sqrt{-1}$)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/I.html) is not a good choice for an index.

Comment: Thank you ! This worked too! What do you mean by $$sqrt(-1)$$?

Comment: @Estaban, click the link to see the Mathematica documentation on `I`.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t).

Answer (score 3):

```
Position[specialColumns, Except[Break], 1, Heads -> False]
```

or

```
Position[specialColumns, _List, 1, Heads -> False]
```

> {{22}, {23}, {24}, {25}, {26}}